# How to add all urls starting with some url to zendesk api client

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I'm making oauth with Zendesk and I need to add redirect urls to api client on Zendesk. What I want to do is to accept all urls that starts with example.com/something/. For example:

[image: For example like this, but with any number after it]

Is it possible to do and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Nikola,

It is not possible to have dynamic redirect URLs. Security is the main reason for this. Is it possible for you to collect whatever data is being used in the path as a parameter?

Comment: In our case it was urls to ticket. I just wrote our workaround, if there is a better way we would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have dynamic redirect URLs.

In our case, we've decided to save that url in cookie. Then we redirect our user from oauth to the same page ("Thank you for allowing access to our app"), and then redirect it to specific url saved in cookie.